# It is possible to create compilers for dynamic languages without losing his dynamic characteristics?

Tags: python, ruby, compiler-construction, compilation, dynamic-languages

Are there some set of reasons that make it impossible for dynamic languages ​​such as Python or Ruby to be compiled instead of interpreted without losing any of his dynamics characteristics?

Of course one the requirements to that hypothetical compiler is that those languages doesn't lose any of his characteristics like metaprogramming, extend objects, add code or modify type system in runtime.

Summarizing, it is possible to create a Ruby or Python compiler without losing any of his characteristics as dynamic programming languages?

Comment: Python *is* compiled. To Python bytecode.

Comment: For me Python is interpreted, compilation to bytecode is only a transformation of original code to be interpreted in a fast way. But finally bytecode is interpreted.

Comment: Languages are *not* compiled nor interpreted. An **implementation** of a language is interpreted or compiled, and even then there isn't a clear distinction. In fact using [futamura's projections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation#Futamura_projections) it's possible to obtain a compiler in an *automatic* way, given an interpreter, hence it's pretty obvious that it **is** possible to create a python/ruby compiler. The real question is: would it be faster, or would it give any advantage at all?

Comment: @jfcalvo: And machine code is just bytecode interpreted by the CPU. The only difference is the number of layers between hardware and the code. Java is interpreted too; by a virtual machine. These lines are not as black and white.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Going even further: there are CPUs which can execute JVM bytecode directly, and there are interpreters for x86 machine code written in Java. Now, what makes an x86 program running in an x86 interpreter on a JVM on an ARM CPU "native" but JVM bytecode running on a JVM bytecode CPU not?

Comment: How do these compilers deal with code which is generated on-the-fly by the already compiled running program? Seems like they would have to embed themselves into their own output.

Comment: @martineau Either that (though that's effectively a JIT compiler and hence hard to do with a compiler designed to work AOT), or it includes an interpreter into the binary.

Comment: I don't see how this question is opinion-based. `it is possible to create a Ruby or Python compiler without losing any of his characteristics as programming languages?`, the answer is yes or no, with an explanation. I'm voting for reopen.

Comment: Edited. I have reformulated the original question. My question is not if is possible to create a compiler for a previously interpreted language (it is obvious that it is possible). My question is "It is possible to create compilers for dynamic programming languages without losing any of his original dynamic characteristics?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely possible to create compilers for dynamic languages. There are a myriad of examples of compilers for dynamic languages in the wild:

- CPython is an implementation of the Python programming language which has a Python compiler.
- PyPy is an implementation of the Python programming language which has a Python compiler.
- Jython is an implementation of the Python programming language which has a Python compiler.
- IronPython is an implementation of the Python programming language which has a Python compiler.
- Pynie is an implementation of the Python programming language which has a Python compiler.
- YARV is an implementation of the Ruby programming language which has a Ruby compiler.
- Rubinius is an implementation of the Ruby programming language which has a Ruby compiler.
- MacRuby is an implementation of the Ruby programming language which has a Ruby compiler.
- JRuby is an implementation of the Ruby programming language which has a Ruby compiler.
- IronRuby is an implementation of the Ruby programming language which has a Ruby compiler.
- MagLev is an implementation of the Ruby programming language which has a Ruby compiler.
- Quercus is an implementation of the PHP programming language which has a PHP compiler.
- P8 is an implementation of the PHP programming language which has a PHP compiler.
- V8 is an implementation of the ECMAScript programming language which has an ECMAScript compiler.

In general, *every* language can be implemented by a compiler, and *every* language can be implemented by an interpreter. It is also possible to *automatically* derive a compiler from an interpreter and vice-versa.

Most modern language implementations use both interpretation and compilation, sometimes even several compilers. Take Rubinius, for example: first Ruby code is compiled to Rubinius bytecode. Rubinius bytecode is then interpreted by the Rubinius VM. Code which has been interpreted several times is then compiled to Rubinius Compiler IR, which is then compiled to LLVM IR, which is then compiled to "native code" (whatever that is). So, Rubinius has one interpreter and three compilers.

V8 is a different example. It actually has *no* interpreter, but two different compilers: one very fast, very memory-efficient compiler which produces unoptimized, somewhat slow code. Code which has been run multiple times is then thrown away, and compiled again with the second compiler, which produces aggressively optimized code but takes more time and uses more memory during compilation.

However, in the end, you *cannot* run code without an interpreter. A compiler cannot run code. A compiler translates a program from one language into a different language. That's it. You can translate all you want, in the end, *something* has to run the code, and that thing is an interpreter. It might be implemented in software or in silicon, but it still is an interpreter.

Comment: "A compiler cannot run code" - well, it can run some code, but it doesn't run your final program or else it wouldn't be called a "compiler", it would be called a "runtime". So for example, C++ templates are a means to trick a compiler into executing code written in a declarative rather than imperative language. The output of this code that the compiler executes is compile-time entities (classes, functions) that form part of the program output by the compiler.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yes, that's what I meant, thanks for clarifying. Of course, the compiler runs code, at the very least it must run the code which performs the compilation. And for cases like C++ Templates, Scala's Turing-complete type system, even overload resolution in C# (which isn't Turing-complete, but can encode any 3-SAT problem) and of course Lisp macros, the compiler needs to either embed an interpreter for that language or compile them before compilation of the "main" program.

Comment: If `you cannot run code without an interpreter`, how does the interpreter run?

Comment: @fotanus: by this definition, a CPU is an interpreter. It runs by pushing electrons around according to some abstract specification.

Comment: @fotanus: the interpreter doesn't have to be code. It could be a human, for example – have you never executed a program in your head or with pen and paper? But the more common case is that the interpreter is implemented in silicon.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just assume by "compile" you mean "compile to native machine code" and leave it for others to challenge this very narrow definition. The answer is a resounding **yes**. In fact, people are doing this right now:

- [Nuitka](http://www.nuitka.net/)
- [Cython](http://cython.org) (actually not Python, but very close and *could* be made to support full Python).
- Various "freezing" tools, though technically those only package the bytecode and a bytecode interpreter into one binary.

However, such a compiler can't perform many (I'd say effectively zero) optimizations, so the resulting code is basically equivalent to what a simple-minded interpreter would do and you only save interpretation overhead (and you lose some nice properties of interpreters, including compact code and faster turnaround). In other words: [Dynamic, correct, fast - choose two](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/181944/7043) (full disclosure: the accepted answer is mine).